# Enviroment variables not available in main.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables

I created project with Vue-CLI 2.9.6 and now I would like use API_URL from .env but it isn't available in main.js. How can I use API_URL from .env in main.js?

Code:

```
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
import axios from 'axios';

import Vue from 'vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';
import store from './store/store';
import Logger from './utils/Logger';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const baseAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
});

Vue.prototype.$http = baseAxios;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
});
```

I need use API_URL because I would like set baseUrl on axios.

Answer (score 0):

> Only variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin. You can access them in your application code:

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code

Comment: I have read the documentation before ask :( I tried API_URL, VUE_APP_API_URL but not working :( Strange because it works in another file with object Logger which has methods of console.log.